# Is there a comprehensive list of mapnprojections implemented in R?

Tags: coordinate-system, r, sf, epsg, terra

I would like to experiment a bit with different and less-frequently used projections in R for global maps, but I am playing a guessing game as of which are actually working.

I tried to look up ESRI or EPSG codes in https://spatialreference.org/ or https://epsg.io/, but some work and some don't. For example, ESRI:102017 works with vectors (sf package), but not with raster (terra package), ESRI:54099 doesn't work at all.

```
library(giscoR)
projected = st_transform(gisco_coastallines, "EPSG:9794")
ggplot()+geom_sf(data=projected)
```

Is there a comprehensive list of map projections available that work in R, so we do not need to go through trial and error?

Some of the projections I would like to use are Guyou, Gringorten, alternative oblique arrangement, Gott-Mugnolo Azimuthal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The projections and projection operations are not implemented in R directly - but in PROJ, which is a standalone library at system level. This library is integrated with R somewhat loosely - you can end up with different versions of PROJ running in two separate installations with the same version of R packages such as {sf} and {terra}. It is a known source of issues.

You will find a list of projections that the current PROJ versions supports at https://proj.org/en/9.3/operations/projections/index.html

Note that you will have to make sure that:

1. you have current (enough) version of PROJ installed - it need not be the latest, but newer versions have more features (and bugs, but I digress)
2. that your {sf} and {terra} are using the same instance of PROJ; this may involve compiling both R packages from source.

Comment: thank you that is useful. However some projections to not work correctly even if just apply to SF objects. For example I have tried the Guyou projection but it cuts off some continents. Maybe R is not really suited for this kind of maps.

Comment: The commonly used projections are usually OK - but yes, there may be a problem with some of the more exotic ones. I can confirm that I can't make Guyou work either.